# 3ds Max - What's the three types of texture maps? 'D, N, S'

Tags: 3ds-max, maps

Using 3ds max, I'm just playing with a model, which I found from a game. I'm not familiar with 3ds max, Hopes the question is not so silly.

It has three types of maps, with 'D', 'N', 'S' suffix. So I guess D for diffuse, N for normal, and S for specular.

The first two seems right. but what's the type of the third one? It doesn't seem to be a specular map, but seems to be the 'metal' parts, so I tried using mix map but the result is also different from in-game result.

The following are the three maps, and my rendered result with in-game result. I think the biggest diffrence - the metallic small decorations, should be what the third map does.

[image: ‘D’ map]
[image: ‘N’ map]
[image: ‘S’ map]
[image: 3dsmax rendered image]
[image: in-game result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the naming conventions of texture files, **the suffix `_S` is generally used for Specular Maps** in Specular workflows, especially in the Unreal Engine (see e.g. [here](https://www.tomlooman.com/ue4-naming-convention/) and [here](https://github.com/Allar/ue5-style-guide) [updated version of first linked article - variations of this article are abound]), **or for Smoothness Maps** in Metalness workflows (see e.g. [here](https://highpriority.com/naming-conventions/)).

**What you have here is a Specular Color map**: it defines the amount of specularity and its color in addition. You can see this in the gold embroidery, for example:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

The effect will be similar to this:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

<sup>[source](https://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC2/Creating+Textures+for+Physically+Based+Shading)</sup>

In Physically Based Rendering, this is only really physically correct when it is used to simulate metallic surfaces (so we can assume the embroidery is made of gold thread):

[image]
<sup>[source](https://substance3d.adobe.com/tutorials/courses/the-pbr-guide-part-2)</sup>

This also implies that the rest of the map is either being 'cheated' on - as obviously not all coloured surfaces here are metals - or that the map is mixed with another map (which is not a far fetch since the 'normal' `_N` map seems to combine a regular tangent normal map with what could be a transparency map).

Answer (score 0):

The S most typically would be smoothness - the inverse of a roughness map. Used often in a PBR metallic rendering workflow.

However, looking at your three maps, I don't think this is a smoothness map, or a specular amount map - but I think it might well be a specular *colour* map - makes the most sense based on your rendered output.